# Is it appropriate to use a website as mobile app

Tags: android, iphone, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I know embedding a website in an in-app browser in a mobile app  could reduce the performance, but since the type of website I'm developing is more or less a blog, I was wondering if the performance should be negligible.

I have searched through Google for any posts addressing this issue and there seems to be none.

Comment: Maybe you can change the title of your question so it refers to the _performance_, which the measurable aspect that worries you, rather than to the _appropriateness_, which is more subjective.

Comment: you should use some of the hybrid approaches to building your app and web site ( such as Ionic framework Or Cordova). There are many more platforms to build such an App.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, but I suggest you to take a look at [Progressive Web Apps (PWA)](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) concept and using it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its very easy to use website in mobile app.